# Get random effect value from pattern of data

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, item-response-theory, mirt

Rasch models are typically fit through an item response theory framework, but can also be estimated through a mixed effects model (e.g., see [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v020i02)). This is highly useful in my case because of some of the reasons the authors mention in the article.

However, when fit through an IRT framework, you can typically estimate theta (respondent ability) for any pattern of response data. I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same when fit through a mixed effects model.

For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mirt)
library(lme4)

d <- as_tibble(expand.table(deAyala))

# Fit model with mirt - typical IRT approach
m_mirt <- mirt(d, model = 1, itemtype = "Rasch")

# Fit mixed effects model with lme4
ld <- d |>
  mutate(respondent_id = seq_len(n())) |>
  pivot_longer(-respondent_id, names_to = "item", values_to = "response")

m_glmer <- glmer(
  response ~ 0 + item + (1 | respondent_id),
  data = ld,
  family = binomial(link = "logit")
)

# comparison
item_compare <- tibble(
  item = 1:5,
  easiness_mirt = map_dbl(coef(m_mirt)[1:5], ~.x[, 2]),
  easiness_glmer = fixef(m_glmer)
)
item_compare
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>    item easiness_mirt easiness_glmer
#>   <int>         <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1     1         2.74           2.71 
#> 2     2         0.826          0.823
#> 3     3         0.375          0.372
#> 4     4        -0.403         -0.406
#> 5     5        -0.630         -0.634

respondent_compare <- tibble(
  respondent_id = seq_len(nrow(d)),
  theta_mirt = fscores(m_mirt)[, 1],
  theta_glmer = coef(m_glmer)$respondent_id[, 1]
)

ggplot(respondent_compare, aes(theta_mirt, theta_glmer)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

When using the mirt package, however, I can get a respondent ability for any pattern of responses, regardless of whether it was represented in the original data or not (these actually probably are represented, but they wouldn't have to be for it to work).

```r
fscores(m_mirt, response.pattern = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
#>              F1     SE_F1
#> [1,] 0.03519389 0.8576724

fscores(m_mirt, response.pattern = rep(0, 5))
#>             F1     SE_F1
#> [1,] -2.322894 0.9651651

fscores(m_mirt, response.pattern = rep(1, 5))
#>            F1     SE_F1
#> [1,] 1.691366 0.9970738
```

Is there anyway to do this same sort of thing, but with the mixed effects model? Essentially taking a response "pattern" and estimating the random effect?

Comment: does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/624928/predict-person-parameters-in-explanatory-irt-with-lme4) discussion answer your question?

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm after! I particularly like the constrained item parameter approach. Thank you! I don't know how I missed that when searching for this earlier.