# Make dataset EFA RMSEA<.05 and TLI>.95

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am using R to do EFA, I tried all the methods to make RMSEA of EFA low, but still around 0.14, and TLI still around 0.6
I am not sure is that possible to make [mydata](https://files.fm/u/mb2hr2pk#_) RMSEA<.05 and TLI>.95
I am asking experts help to analysis mydata, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by this analysis?

Comment: I want to use EFA to get the good factors and then delete some bad items.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the variables/data and what have you tried so far?  As far as I see from the linked data file, all your variables are binary. Why do you think that factor analysis is an appropriate method for the analysis of such data?

Comment: Factor analysis is the good way to determine nature and number of latent variables.you have 60 variables and 1000+ obs, it's enough for EFA.It's better if you set 4 factors.

Comment: It's problematic to use factor analysis on binary variables. Please see the related questions for various approaches [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/doing-principal-component-analysis-or-factor-analysis-on-binary-data-using-spss) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data).

Comment: Except FA, any other method to understand the factor structure?