# Need PCA or other dimensionality reduction with mixed type variables, before doing clustering

Tags: clustering, pca, mixed-type-data

I have a fairly large dataset of 171 mixed variables (104 dichotomous/qualitative, and 67 continuous). My goal is to build a typology of agricultural systems.

I originally used a PCA to reduce the dimensionality of the data and use the PCA factors to do a cluster analysis and determine the typologies. The results had some sense but I felt I was loosing key information since I´ll use the clusters for further analysis.

I have realized that I might be making a mistake by PCA (with all those dichotomous variables). I have found alternative analysis for data reduction (PCAMix, FactoMineR), however, I dont know how to use the separate results of a PCA, MCA or FAMD to later, perform a Cluster Analysis.

I appreciate any insights. I´m working on R and SPSS.

Comment: Describe a bit more your dichotomous variables

Comment: they are binary 1 and  0. 
Many of them were nominal variables at first, and I created new variables with each possible value, and when that "trait" is present I give it a 1 and not present a 0.

For example:

Original variable "Irrigation system": 
A= Dripping; B= Surface; C= Manual; D= None; E= Dripping and manual.

I created 4 new binary variables: "Dripping"; "Surface"; "Manual"; "None", and filled them with 1/0. (Because in some cases both are present). 

Hope it is clear :/
Thanks

Comment: Categorical PCA (found under Optimal Scaling) menu item is a way to go. Do not use the binary dummies, input the categorical variables themselves (along with scale variables). You should read some literature first to use the method, because it is a bit more complex than linear PCA.

Comment: Start with some info here. This one https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/215404/3277, then search threads mentioning "CATPCA".

Comment: Thank you. Will look to it. 

Just a last question, since the data set is mixed, I supposed I´ll run the CATPCA with categorical, and then normal PCA with the continuous. 

Would I be able to join the results of this two analysis to then runa Cluster analysis with the factors obtained from PCAs?

Comment: CATPCA takes input of continuous and categorical variables at once. It is PCA that allows for a mixture of data types.

Comment: Great! 
Recoding all the categorical values, and will try it. Thanks so much.