# Is there a problem if variables have different levels in factor analysis?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I'm planning to do a factor analysis on data with ordinal variables 1-5, 1-6 and 1-3. I'm new to factor analysis and I wonder if there is any problem that the factors have different levels? Thanks in advance! I'm planning to use the r package psych

Comment: `the factors have different levels` what does it mean?

Comment: variables are set as factors with levels 1-3/1-5/1-6

Answer (score 0):

There will be the usual problems of factor analyzing ordinal variables, but there are no additional problems because of different scales - these get dealt with in the analysis.

But treating the variables as if they were continuous is not going to be correct.

[See this question and the answers thereto.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data)