# Spearman coefficient and PCA

Tags: self-study, spearman-rho

I have a question about the Spearman rank correlation coefficient. In this reference (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.16224.pdf, Fig. 4) they use the spearman correlation coefficient instead of the standard correlation coefficient to perform PCA. This is for me appealing because it removes the need of normalization when the variables have different units. But the theory I know about PCA diagonalizes the Pearson correlation matrix. So my question is:

- Is it common to perform PCA on top of the Spearman rank correlation coefficient? Is there a theory behind this?

Comment: Point 6 https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/215404/3277

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I should remove this question or should I leave it as a reference?

Comment: I would leave it.

Comment: There needn't be any theory: if an exploratory method like PCA with rank correlation leads to an insight, you can be satisfied.