# How to test overall skewness / normality in a large data set of ordinal data in R?

Tags: r, skewness, psychology, skew-normal-distribution

I want to test overall skewness / normality in a large data set of ordinal data from survey questions and was wondering how this can be done?

(I couldn’t use Shapiro wilk as I received an error saying the dataset is too large as it has over 20,000 data points)

I have used these R commands so far but not sure if they are appropriate or the best option

describe(DATAFRAME)

boxplot(DATAFRAME)

Answer (score 2):

This is a hopeless task.

- Ordinal data is ordered categories; you can only have normality with continuous data over the real line. Normality is literally impossible.
- With ordinal data, "skewness" doesn't really make a lot of sense either. Certainly moment-skewness would not be meaningful, but even a pure quantile-based skewness would rely on comparisons of distances, which again, are not going to make sense with data where the distances between the ordinal categories are not specified. It might be possible to come up with *some* measure of "skewness" that just relates to the ordering but I don't think it's going to be much use. (Visually, most of the values are near the top of the range and in that sense you might reasonably argue that there is some sense in which the values are left skewed, but I think there's perhaps a better way to describe it that doesn't end up seeming to treat the values as interval scaled.)
- your boxplot is not super-useful as well. It's not a good way to display these data. Why not a set of bar charts or stacked striphcarts (some programs might call it a "dot plot") of the proportions in each category, one for each group on a common set of axes? That way you get the whole distribution. With a little care over how exactly you display it, it shouldn't take much more space than your boxplots did.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help this is much appreciated. The reason I'm asking is I heard I need to make sure my data is not too skewed or 'non-normal' to run an exploratory factor analysis (EFA). Would you or anyone reading this happen to know given I am running an EFA whether normality/skew becomes important for ordinal data? If so I was thinking of trying to transform the data to make it normal but given what you have said I'm not sure if that is possible...

Comment: You should have led with that information. To run an EFA you would have to begin by assuming your variables were interval scaled (since you're constructing linear combinations of them), not ordinal; however they still *could not be normal*. If you do treat them as interval scaled, your variables will still be discrete (seemingly only taking the values $\{0.1,2,3,4,5\}$), so certainly not normal -- not even approximately, and are very strongly left skew.

Comment: okay thank you very much. So if I am assuming the variables are interval scales, should I try and transform the data to make it normal? Or is that not possible given the discrete nature of the data

Comment: @izzi3880 Don't try to change your data to fit the analysis. Change the analysis to fit the (fundamental properties of) the data.

Comment: See this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data

Comment: @Roland  +1 and applause.

Comment: @izzi3880 Transformation won't help (or at least barely). e.g. 1. It will still be a discrete distribution on 6 outcomes, e.g. 2. Some of the variables have the last category as the highest; any monotonic transformation will still leave the last category as the highest. 3. With transformation you are changing the distances between the categories immediately asserting they were the same. Start by talking about what the underlying aim is (rather than following some recipe that doesn't seem to match your ingredients), and try to find a way to achieve that aim the variables you have.

Comment: For that purpose, I think you'd need a new question at this point, but there may be some thinking required as well. e.g. what was the EFA *for*?

Comment: Thank you very much everyone this helps a lot and is very much appreciated. I feel like I have a much better idea now - thank you

Comment: rereading my  second comment ("*Transformation won't help...*"), it seems insufficiently clear. Item 2 in that comment talks about the last category as being the "highest", but what I meant is "category with the highest proportion of responses in it", not highest in terms of the value of the category labels. The point being that any monontonic transformation still leaves the most selected category at the top end.